# Using Assembly from GAC in .NET Office Addin

Tags: .net, excel, dll, reference, add-in

I wrote an Excel-Addin to cusomise the Office 2007/2010/2013-Ribbon with Visual Studio 2010.
The Addin is a .NET DLL with COM Interop and loaded correctly at ExcelStartup.
The Addin has a reference to a second DLL (also .NET with COM Interop) called `Main.dll`.

At deployment the `Main.dll` is copied to the Global Assembly Cache Microsoft Intermediate Language: GAC_MSIL as it is compiled for AnyCPU. So this works fine for Excel 32bit and 64bit. The DLL behaves as it should and may be referenced and used from any Excel-Version above 2003.

The Excel-Addin is copied to a program directory together with different Excel-Workbooks.
Usually managed code finds references if they are placed and registered in the GAC. The Addin does not. I have to place a second copy of the `Main.dll` file into the same directory.

I would like to keep the file system small and therefore avoid a second copy of the dll-file.

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.  You can only get an accurate answer when you show the trace it produces.  There are two GACs, one for CLR v2.0 in c:\windows\assembly, another for CLR v4.0 in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly.  So rough guess is that you used the wrong one.

Comment: Thank You Hans. Fuslogvw showed that GAC lookup failed. I installed my DLL unsing nsis and reigstration via resasm. After I started gacutil the managed dll was registered correctly. I assume, I habe to change my install-script to deploy my dlls using gacutil.

Comment: I get confused sometimes with COMInterop. At deployment, I copy the files to GAC and use Regasm to register the type library. This is enough to load the dll into COMInterop using `createObject("...")`. For managed dlls to be loaded this is not enough. As I use NSIS to deploy I decided to stay with an additional copy in the executiing directory. GacUtil is not recommended for deployment and I want to stay with NSIS.